# Scheduled Task Naming Conventions?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, best-practices

I would like to hear of examples of a naming convention for Scheduled Tasks in Windows, along with rationale.

Thanks.

Comment: I name all of my scheduled tasks "Bob". It's a little confusing remembering which one is which, but after a while you get used to it.

Comment: I know there is not an objective answer to this question that is true for all people at all times.  However, I don't think it is opinion-based in the sense of "What is the best naming convention?" or "Which is better, Windows or *nix?".  I am simply asking for concrete examples of existing naming conventions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since most of my Windows scheduled tasks execute Powershell scripts, and my Powershell scripts usually consist of one or more functions that are designed to carry out a specific, discrete task, and I always strive to use approved Powershell verbs and verb-noun nomenclature when designing PS functions, I end up naming most of my scheduled tasks the same name as the Powershell script that they execute. For example, my scheduled tasks might be named `Send-PasswordExpiryNotificationEmail` because it executes a Powershell script named `Send-PasswordExpiryNotificationEmail.ps1`, and it does what it sounds like... sends emails to Active Directory users whose passwords are about to expire soon.

Powershell has definitely shaped my thinking about how I do scheduled tasks from now on. I prefer many, modular scheduled tasks that can flipped on and off to enable and disable small bits of functionality, rather than one or two monolithic scheduled tasks that do everything.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say really since scheduled tasks are likely to be relatively proprietary. With that said, I typically name the task by the department that needs the task run followed by the script that it is running...

This way I can sort by name, go directly to the group/application that "owns" the task and find it from there.

Typically I only have a couple hundred tasks so it is not a big deal...